# Dynamic class extend

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way to define a class so that it extends another class only if that other class is available?

Comment: This doesn't make lot of sense from an architectural perspective - either you need to extend a class or you don't. What are you trying to achieve? (There might be an easier way.)

Comment: There should be no reason to dynamically create classes, you should have a solid system that should never require such a thing. unless as stated above, there might be a simpler approach to your goal.

Comment: RobertPitt is 100% correct.  I would rethink the problem because it sounds like there is a larger error in structure that should be looked into first.

Comment: See my solution below, which actually solves your dilemma directly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9898049/441739

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing that would allow you to do

```
class Foo extendsIfExist Bar
```

But you can monkeypatch Foo with [runkit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php)'s

- [`runkit_class_adopt` — Convert a base class to an inherited class, add ancestral methods when appropriate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-class-adopt.php)

Example from PHP Manual:

```
class myParent {
  function parentFunc() {
    echo "Parent Function Output\n";
  }
}

class myChild {
}

runkit_class_adopt('myChild','myParent');
myChild::parentFunc();
```

The runkit extension is available from PECL. However, **it's use is discouraged** because needing it is almost always an indicator for a flawed design.

---

*Disclaimer: I am only assuming something like the following example is the reason why you are asking your question. Disregard that part of the answer if it's not.*

If you need certain functionality conditionally at runtime, consider aggregating the class you want to extend from, e.g. try something along the lines of

```
interface Loggable
{
    public function log($message);
}
class Foo implements Loggable
{
    protected $logger;
    public function setLogger($logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function log($message)
    {
        if($this->logger !== NULL) {
            return $this->logger->log($message);
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, the functionality we want is `log()`. So instead of detecting if a logger class is available and then monkeypatching this functionality into our Foo class, we tell it to require this functionality by adding an interface Loggable. If a Logger class exists, we instantiate and aggregate it in Foo. If it doesnt exist, we can still call log but it wont do anything. This is much more [solid](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Comment: Solution to provide "extend if exist" without using eval: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9898049/441739

Answer (score 4):

I did it on this way.

```
if (class_exists('parentClass') {
  class _myClass extends parentClass {}
} else {
  class _myClass {}
}
class myClass extends _myClass
{
...
}
```

Comment: Error if files are external `Fatal error:  Class declarations may not be nested`

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer and an extention to Pekka's answer.

Firstly at Pekka, i think the eval is totally wrong, what is wrong with

```
if(class_exists("bar"))
{
     class foo extends bar
     {

     }
}
```

that is also my answer aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered a similar requirement recently, where a class in my library needed to dynamically extend from ClassB (if exists), otherwise extend from Class A.

My solution (my code is namespaced, same concept applies regardless):

```
namespace someNamespace;

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if (strcasecmp($class, 'someNamespace\SomeFakeClass') === 0) {
        if (class_exists('ClassB',false)) {
            class_alias('ClassB', 'someNamespace\SomeFakeClass');
        } else {
            class_alias('ClassA', 'someNamespace\SomeFakeClass');
        }
    }
}, true, true);

/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
/** @noinspection PhpUndefinedNamespaceInspection */
class MyClass extends \someNamespace\SomeFakeClass {
    # ... real logic here ...
}
```

Using the above solution, the class **MyClass** will dynamically inherit from **ClassB** if exists, otherwise it inherits from **ClassA**.

This solution avoids using **eval**, which is a big plus for me.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Just a note, the @noinspection notation exists so that IDEs such as PHPStorm will not report errors regarding the non-existent class.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
<?php

class Foo{
}

if( class_exists('Foo') ){
    class SubFoo extends Foo{
    }
}

if( class_exists('Bar') ){
    class SubBar extends Bar{
    }
}

$a = new SubFoo; // OK
$b = new SubBar; // Fatal error: Class 'SubBar' not found
```

Comment: Not nice either, but better than the `eval()` approach!